# Prime Number Iterator class not including start parameter first prime number

Tags: python

This is my `PrimeNo` and `PrimeNoIterator` class. `start` and `stop` define the endpoints of the range over which iteration will occur. Both endpoints are included in this range.

```
class PrimeNo:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return PrimeNoIter(self.start, self.stop)
        
class PrimeNoIter:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start, self.stop = start, stop
        
    def __next__(self):
        if self.start < self.stop:
           self.start += 1
           i = 1
           while i < (self.start//2+1):
                if self.start % i == 0:
                   self.start = self.start+1
                   if self.start > self.stop:
                       raise StopIteration
                   i = 1
                i += 1
           else:
                return self.start
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Now when I test this, I am not getting the right output.

```
primes = PrimeNo(1, 20)
for prime in primes:
    print(prime, end=" ")
print()

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 #Expect
3 5 7 11 13 17 19 #Got
```

Test2:

```
primes = PrimeNo(11, 31)
for prime in primes:
    print(prime, end=" ")
print()
11 13 17 19 23 29 31 #Expect
13 17 19 23 29 31  #Got
```

Comment: The problem is with i=1 and if self.start % i == 0. Ih the first iteration it will always reject self.start+1

Comment: How do I deal with this?

Comment: Try making i=2 to start with and debug.

Answer (score 0):

First thing your `__next__` does is it increments `self.start`. Only then it tests whether `self.start` is prime. That's why if `start` is a prime number, it isn't included - your code skips over it and test start + 1.

The simples (not necessarily best) solution is to return PrimeIter(self.start-1, self.end) from **iter** method. That way first number considered for being prime is (self.start - 1) + 1 = self.start.

Edit:
It took me a while to understand how `__next__` is suppose to work. I think it's quite tricky because in one `while` loop you handle `self.start` and `i` incrementing. Anyway, here is a working code:

```
class PrimeNo:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return PrimeNoIter(self.start, self.stop)
        
class PrimeNoIter:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start, self.stop = start, stop
        
    def __next__(self):
        if self.start <= 2 <= self.stop:
            self.start = 3
            return 2

        i = 2
        while i < self.start // 2 + 1:
            if self.start > self.stop:
                raise StopIteration
            if self.start % i == 0:
                self.start += 1
                i = 2
            else:
                i += 1

        self.start += 1
        return self.start - 1
```

here is same method written in more clear way:

```
class PrimeNo:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return PrimeNoIter(self.start, self.stop)
        
class PrimeNoIter:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start, self.stop = start, stop
        
    def __next__(self):
        if self.start < 2:
            self.start = 2

        for num in range(self.start, self.stop + 1):
            self.start = num + 1
            for i in range(2, num // 2 + 1):
                if num % i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                return num

        raise StopIteration
```

and here splitted into readable methods:

```
class PrimeNo:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return PrimeNoIter(self.start, self.stop)
        
class PrimeNoIter:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start, self.stop = start, stop

    @staticmethod
    def is_prime(num):
        for i in range(2, num // 2 + 1):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
        
    def __next__(self):
        if self.start < 2:
            self.start = 2

        for num in range(self.start, self.stop + 1):
            self.start = num + 1
            if self.is_prime(num):
                return num

        raise StopIteration
```

and here with some generator comprehension shenanigans :D

```
class PrimeNo:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return PrimeNoIter(self.start, self.stop)
        
class PrimeNoIter:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start, self.stop = start, stop
        
    def __next__(self):
        if self.start < 2:
            self.start = 2

        for num in range(self.start, self.stop + 1):
            self.start = num + 1
            if all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2, num // 2 + 1)):
                return num

        raise StopIteration
```

Sorry it took so long, I think I didn't quite grasp the problem at the beginning :D

Comment: But that way for `primes = PrimeNo(1, 20)` I get `1 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 `

Comment: Then you should change your __next__ function to not accept 1 as prime. Something like: ```if self.start < 2: self.start = 2``` should suffice

Comment: can you please tell me where in the code should I mention this, as in what line?

Comment: At the very beginning of `__next__` method

Comment: I'm not able to get the right output, can you please edit the code and show it as a comment? Its giving `time limit exceeded` error

Comment: ```def __next__(self):
        if self.start < 1: self.start = 1
        if self.start < self.stop:
           self.start += 1
           i = 1
           while i < (self.start//2+1):
                if self.start % i == 0:
                   self.start = self.start+1
                   if self.start > self.stop:
                       raise StopIteration
                   i = 1
                i += 1
           else:
                return self.start
        else:
            raise StopIteration```

Comment: can you please edit your answer and include this? It is not clear like this

Comment: Not really, sorry

Comment: Okay sure I understand. But can you tell me any other way in which I can tackle this bug? I don't really think this seems to be working. It still shows a time limit error

Comment: I think, the -1 is necessary, but to get rid of "1" printed as prime you could change the PrimeNoIter init to: ```self.start, self.stop = max(start, 1), stop```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work:(

Comment: okay, I found a moment to edit the answer. Hope it's clear now :D